# How to extract the time using R from a MATLAB serial date number?

Tags: r, matlab

I have some MATLAB serial date number that I need to use in R but I havt to convert them to a normal date.

```
    Matlab:
   datestr(733038.6)
    ans =
    27-Dec-2006 14:24:00
```

you can see it gives the date and time.

```
Now we try in R:
Matlab2Rdate <- function(val) as.Date(val - 1, origin = '0000-01-01') 
> Matlab2Rdate(733038.6)
[1] "2006-12-27"
```

It gives only the date but I need also the time? Any idea

Comment: Check this link http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2011/02/converting-matlab-and-r-date-and-time-values/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is Matlab uses "January 01, 0000", a fictional reference date, to calculate its date number. The origin of time for the "POSIXct" class in R is, ‘1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC’. You can read about how different systems handle dates [here](http://127.0.0.1:17958/library/base/html/as.Date.html).

Before converting, you need to account for this difference in reference from one format to another. The [POSIX](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) manual contains such an example. Here's my output:

```
> val<-733038.6
> as.POSIXct((val - 719529)*86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2006-12-27 14:23:59 UTC"
```

Where 719529 is ‘1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC’ in Matlab's datenum and [86400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) the number of seconds in an standard UTC day.